# How to run coverage report with parallel pytest using xdist and django_coverage_plugin

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py, pytest-django

Using the following setup, the calculated coverage is less than if I use a single thread without parallelization. Coverage creates only 1 coverage file in the project root directory, which I expect is where the problem lies.

I cannot identify what I am doing wrong, the reported coverage is less than if I simply run `coverage -m pytest` (on a single thread). The tests themselves run in parallel just fine.

Can anyone identify my mistake? I wonder if an environment variable is missing. I run the command from the project root, which contains `.coveragerc` and `sitecustomize.py`.

`coverage erase && COVERAGE_PROCESS_START=./.coveragerc coverage run --concurrency=multiprocessing --parallel-mode -m pytest -n 8 && coverage combine && coverage report`

sitecustomize.py

```py
import coverage

coverage.process_startup()
```

.coveragerc

```
[run]
include = 
    lettergun/*
omit = 
    *migrations*
    *tests*
    *.html
plugins = django_coverage_plugin
parallel = True
concurrency = multiprocessing
branch = True
```

pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --ds=config.settings.test --reuse-db -n 8
python_files = test_*.py
norecursedirs = node_modules
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = config.settings.test
```

Comment: Hey @John, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: i did not. I run the tests slowly when generating the coverage report and in parallel when i dont care about the coverage report.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1341 provides some context (and possible solution to this), specially this comment: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1341#issuecomment-1302863172

I tried to add the `coverage-enable-subprocess` package but didn't get it to work.

I switched to use `pytest-cov` and got coverage report when using `pytest-xdist`)